# Django not rendering information to the database

Tags: python, django

so I have been trying to save the information from the frontend to the backend in Django. However when I check my database on Django it is not there. Can you please check what I am doing wrong because I just want the email and password in the database. Im fairly new at Django. Thank you!

view.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render

from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
#from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

#from . import views
# Create your views here.

def login(request):
    return render(request, 'login.html')

def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            #username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            #raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            #user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            #login(request, user)
            return redirect('login.html')
        else:
            form = UserCreationForm()
        return render(request, 'templates/signup_form.html', {'form': form})
    return render(request, 'signup_form.html')
```

signup_form.html

```
{% extends 'signup.html' %}

{% block body %}

    <form method = "post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p}}
    </form>

{% endblock %}
```

models.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
```

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.11.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '*o7vg-hqbcx9bqh6fcg^daw21(#2bb8ik14-^02e!nus*y##&c'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    { #['./website/static'],
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['./website/templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "website", "static"),
)
```

Comment: Your Form needs an "action" attribute (action="/your-path/"), and also you need a Form Class. Besides the urls.py and settings.py also should be configured correctly (post them if your problem didn't resolved). see [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to submit your form to the same url, but throught a post request hence, you need to provide `.` as the value for your `action` variable in the form

Add a `action` variable to your signup form as follows

```
<form method = "post" action=".">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p}}
</form>
```

Your view doesnt have way to handle `get` requests to the `signup` url, which is caused due to an extra indent.
Change the signup view as follows

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            #username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            #raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            #user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            #login(request, user)
            return redirect('login.html')
        else:
            #this means the form is not valid
            #so you need to provide the varibles as they were submitted, so the user can change it to proper values
            form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
    else:
        #this is when the user sends get request 
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'templates/signup_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: i implemented it in. I still dont see data pop in. What am i still missing? Thank you!!

Comment: How are you checking the values are present or not?

Comment: I am checking on the django admin database it also doesnt do the redirection so that too, haha

Comment: Just if the control is moving inside the `form.is_valid()` condition, Use print statements for now. But look into how to use `logging` library

Comment: no, I just figured to give it to you anyway for your help. Im still looking at why its not popping up though, it seems right though..

Comment: Best practice when debugging is using `logging`. Add `logging.debug` at all the conditional blocks, and then check how the flow is happening inside the code. from your server logs (in terminal if you are using development server). Also dont forget to refresh the admin console.

Answer (score 2):

Move `else` clause of inner `if form.is_valid()` to outer `if request.method == 'POST'` and remove last `return` statement.

Your **signup** view should look like.

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
            # ...
            # redirect to a new URL:
            return redirect('login.html')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'templates/signup_form.html', {'form': form})
```

> Reference:
>   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#the-view